# Catching Power BI queries

Tags: sql-server, ssas, powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

How I can catch Power BI queries on Import mode? For Direct Query I can just connect profiler to server, but for Import I have only model.

I need it to check how some complicated reports work.

Answer (score 2):

You could still connect (SQL Server?) Profiler to your server, but manually trigger the Refresh - either using Power BI Desktop or from the Dataset's menu in app.powerbi.com (if using a gateway).

Note it might not give you the full picture as the Edit Queries capability can rival the most complex ETL processes - most of that wont hit your database.  Probably the real answer to your 2nd para is that you need to open the source .pbix file using Power BI Desktop.